# インスタンス元のIPアドレスをコピー先に引越ししたい

Tags: aws, vpc

AMIによるインスタンスのコピーで別のVPCへ引越しすることはできたのですが、インスタンス元のIPアドレスをコピー先に引越しすることは可能なのでしょうか。インスタンス元にはElasticIPアドレスを付与していない状況です。
よろしくお願いします。

参考にした記事
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance

Comment: 「サービスを停止しないように」とはどのような状態を求めているのか明確にしてください。プロセスが起動したままですか？ それとも「インスタンス元のIPアドレスをコピー先に引越し」が実現すれば十分なのですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
「これまでのサービスを停止しないように」と記載していますが、「インスタンス元のIPアドレスをコピー先に引越し」ができればいいと思っています。
何かわかればよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @cubick 「サービス停止せずに」は補足情報でしかなく、タイトルに含めるべきではなさそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Amazon EC2 インスタンスの IP アドレス指定](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html)にて

> #### パブリック IPv4 アドレスと外部 DNS ホスト名
>
> パブリック IP アドレスは、Amazon のパブリック IPv4 アドレスプールからインスタンスに割り当てられ、お客様の AWS アカウントには関連付けられません。パブリック IP アドレスをインスタンスから割り当て解除すると、そのパブリック IPv4 アドレスはパブリック IP アドレスプールに戻され、再利用することはできません。

> #### Elastic IP アドレス (IPv4)
>
> Elastic IP アドレスは、アカウントに割り当てることができるパブリック IPv4 アドレスです。このアドレスとインスタンスを関連付けたり、その関連付けを解除したりできます。アドレスはアカウントに割り当てられ、割り当てを解除するまでアカウントに残ります。

と説明されているように、Elastic IP アドレスを使用していない場合は、アドレスを再利用できません。Elastic IPを使用する必要があります。

Comment: やっぱり方法はないですよね…
ご回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: @Tomoyazelda ありがとうコメントは不要です。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) に沿って解決済みとしていただけたらと思います。